# How to append data into a excel sheet column?

Tags: c#, excel

I have existing Excel file with some data and I want to append data to it...
![enter image description here][1]

```
try
{
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "http://csharp.net-informations.com";
    xlWorkBook.Save();
    Object newpath = path + "Chat_Competitors.xls";
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(newpath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
    xlApp.Quit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.ToString());
}
```

this is what I done. but I want to append..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To append to an existing excel file, find the last row and increment it by 1

```
int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
                              "*",
                              xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,1],
                              Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas,
                              Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                              Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                              Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                              misValue,
                              misValue,
                              misValue
                              ).Row + 1;
```

and then simply write to that row

Comment: looks like there is no built in function there. anyway this will help. thanks.

Comment: this is the best option I got.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You must open the existing file instead of create a new.

```
var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path + "Chat_Competitors.xls");
```