# How to pass data from C# to an excel existing file

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I want to make a button which you press for passing data from 3 textboxes to an excel table but I want to use the same table every time and just add data to a new row. Every time I want to add something, it creates me a new excel file. Here's my code.

```
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Book name";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Author";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Rating";

        string curFile = @"g:\Biblioteca.xls";

        if (!File.Exists(curFile))
        {
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("g:\\Biblioteca.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[++k, 1] = getName;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[k, 2] = getAuthor;    
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[k, 3] = getRating;
            MessageBox.Show("Excel created succesfuly");
        }
        else
        {

            Excel.Application excelApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(curFile,
                    0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                    true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[++k, 1] = getName;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[k, 2] = getAuthor;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[k, 3] = getRating;
        }
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();


    }
```

}

Comment: Why don't you try to use OleDb for this?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the problem you are having? When you say it creates a new file, are you saying that it goes into the `if(!File.Exists(curFile))` block? Do you get the `Excel created succesfuly` message, or is it getting into the `else` block yet creating a new file?

Comment: Take a look at the following SO questions, they may provide you with the proper way to do what you are wanting. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142488/how-to-append-data-into-a-excel-sheet-column and Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659069/writing-data-to-an-existing-excel-file-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You are not opening any existing file!

See @gmiley's second reference for an example of opening an existing spreadsheet. You may need to study `Range` to work out how to place your new data.